# handling map tiles

Tags: c#, api, dictionary

I want to build a C# app using map. I want it to contain the map.

1. where to find a world map that can be saved on my computer.
2. How to handle the map zoom level and center point?

maybe there is a good api for accessing the map object?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find a wide variety of maps at the [Xplanet Maps](http://xplanet.sourceforge.net/maps.php) page. You didn't specify what kind of map you wanted, or what scale, so you may need to be more specific in what you want.